# Python Selenium Function In Seperate File - NameError

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am building a Python script and want to split up certain functions into separate files to make maintenance easier.

I have two files currently called main.py and function1.py

**main.pydef**

```
#Setup Imports
import os
import os.path
import sys


# Import Functions
from function1 import myfunction


#Setup Selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver


#Launch Firefox
def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    return driver   

  url_list = ['http://www.example.com/page1', 'http://www.example.com/contact', 'http://www.example.com/about', 'http://www.example.com/test'];

driver = init_driver()

# Init Blank List
checked_urls = []

for url in url_list:
    myfunction(driver)

print(checked_urls)
```

**function1.py**

```
def myfunction(driver):

    driver.get(url)
    htmlText = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#phrase").text

    if "This Is My Phrase" in htmlText:
        checked_urls.extend(['PHRASE_FOUND'])
    else:
        checked_urls.extend(['PHRASE_FOUND'])
```

I am trying to get it to visit each URL in the list and check for **This Is My Phrase** on the page.  If it finds it then it should add to the list.

I am seeing the following error when running the script...

```
NameError: name 'url' is not defined
```

I am pretty sure it's related to the way I am importing the separate function but can't work out whats wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: It's not about importing! Try to look at your `myfunction()` as independent function... There is no variable called `url`. I guess you should add `url` to function args: `myfunction(driver, url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also pass url variable to myfunction:

```
def myfunction(driver, url):

    driver.get(url)
    htmlText = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#phrase").text

    if "This Is My Phrase" in htmlText:
        checked_urls.extend(['PHRASE_FOUND'])
    else:
        checked_urls.extend(['PHRASE_FOUND'])
```

Then in main file:

```
for url in url_list:
    myfunction(driver, url)
```

Comment: That makes sense, would I also need to pass the checked_urls as well?

Comment: You'd better declare `checked_urls=[]` inside  `myfunction()` and let it `return checked_urls`

Answer (score 1):

I think some code should be corrected:

Frist, delete the blank space before `url_list`:

```
  #url_list = ['http://www.example.com/page1', 'http://www.example.com/contact', 'http://www.example.com/about', 'http://www.example.com/test'];
url_list = ['http://www.example.com/page1', 'http://www.example.com/contact', 'http://www.example.com/about', 'http://www.example.com/test'];
```

Then, the `url` is a local variable, it's not directly accessible in the function `myfunction`. But it can be accessed as a function parameter:

```
def myfunction(driver, url):
    ...
```